# PULP SDK (platform-rtl)

Tags: riscv

I'm following the tutorial on PULP SDK build process "https://github.com/pulp-platform/pulp-sdk/blob/b38dabd571287b6183f17a2c5538382b9d3fe668/README.md".  I'm blocked at the stage of SDK build when I tape the command "$ make all" and I can't understand what's mean these errors.

ImportError: No module named 'sphinx'
Makefile:56: recipe for target 'html' failed
make[2]: *** [html] Error 1
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
Reached EOF with exit status 2
FATAL ERROR: the command 'build' has failed
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 255

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, this error is caused by not (correctly) installing the pulp-riscv-gnu-toolchain.

So you should first install this toolchain which can be found here https://github.com/pulp-platform/pulp-riscv-gnu-toolchain.

After that you should follow the steps for "Installation (Pulp)" and replace the command for `make` to `sudo make`.

Now you can return to your tutorial on PULP SDK build process.

In case you are still encountering the same error than you should execute this command which I found here [cannot open libmpfr.so.4 after update on ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51288467/cannot-open-libmpfr-so-4-after-update-on-ubuntu-18-04)

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpfr.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpfr.so.4
```

" Bear in mind that this is just workaround which might trigger other issues for your case. However, this might save you the day in cases when the problematic program is just a mean to achieve something else."