# cross-compile error while loading shared library

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling, ubuntu-18.04

I have run gcc cross compiler from ubuntu(x86) to arm. **this cross compiler works fine on ubuntu 14**, and not I try in on ubuntu 18.

I tried to compile simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    printf("h\n");
}

gcc test.c -o test
```

**When I compile it with gcc (to x86) all works fine**, but when I compile it with cross compiler arm gcc I got error `...arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabu/4.*.*/cc1 : error while loading shared libraries: libmpfr.so.4 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

When I serach I can find`libmpfr.so.4` in the cross compiler path under /usr/lib

So even `arm-gcc test.c -o test -L "<path_to_compiler>/usr/lib"` got same error .   and even `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path_to_compiler>/usr/lib` didn't help

Comment: Can't imagine this will fix it but did you try and pass in the library directory explicitly?

Comment: @jiveturkey yes, I update my post

Comment: Where did you get the ARM toolchain from? Did you build it on your own? How has that compiler been configured, ie what's the output of `arm-gcc -v`?

Comment: `arm-gcc test.c -o test /usr/lib/libmpfr.so.4` should work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot open libmpfr.so.4 after update on ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51288467/cannot-open-libmpfr-so-4-after-update-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: @Jim West `arm-gcc test.c -o test /usr/lib/libmpfr.so.4` got same error

Comment: @emacs drives me nuts yes, I have build this toolchain by own , version is 4.9

Comment: @parser1234 In that case I'd recommend you read the installation instructions again, in particular how to get the prerequisites (GMP, MPFR, MPC,...) right by using `./contrib/download_prerequisites`. In the case you configured in the source directory (which is not supported btw) get the sources again and stick to the documentation.